# Copy constructor of subclass that has its own variables

Tags: java, inheritance, copy-constructor

I have a subclass called CDAccount that has its own variables that aren't defined in the super class.

```
private Calendar maturityDate;
private int termOfCD;
```

The subclass also has a copy constructor that takes in a superclass object.

```
public CDAccount(Account cd){
    super(cd);
}
```

This constructor is called by this line of code that's in a different class.

```
if (accounts.get(index).getType().equals("CD")) {
return new CDAccount(accounts.get(index));
}
```

I'm looking for a way to set the subclass variables in the copy constructor. I thought I would be able to do it with the object it takes in, because I created the object as a subclass object before setting it into the array of superclass objects.

Comment: Since you are accepting Account type, you need to check if the object you get is CDAccount and cast it, then assign variables after super(cd). Or you could just only accept CDAccount as parameter in CDAccount class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting should do the trick for you:

```
public CDAccount(Account cd) {
    super(cd);
    if(cd instanceof CDAccount) {
        this.maturityDate = ((CDAccount)cd).maturityDate;
        this.termOfCD=((CDAccount)cd).termOfCD;
    }
    else {
        this.maturityDate = null;
        this.termOfCD= null;
    }
}
```

This works because of the way encapsulation is implemented in Java: private variables are accessible to other instances of the same class.

Comment: using instanceof is not a good practice because the encapsulation principle of OOP. [Encapsulation](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/)

Comment: ended up writing my own solution before reading this, but i can confirm this works. though with the way i reach the constructor the if else statement is not necessary. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be overloading the constructor like this.

```
public CDAccount(CDAccount cd){
    super(cd);
    this.maturityDate = cd.getMaturityDate()
    this.termOfCD = cd.getTermOfCD()
}

public CDAccount(Account cd){
    super(cd);
}
```

This works for me on Java JDK v10.1